# Excel Select Drop Down List Item

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a function in Excel 2013 that would allow me to select a Drop Down List Value based on the value of another field?

For Example: I want to have 2 options in my Drop Down List (True and False). If a specific cell = 0 then I want False to be automatically selected in my list.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to use a simple formula in the cell itself. For example `=A1=0` which will return either 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' or `=IF(A1=0, "True", "False")` which will return either 'True' or 'False'. In any case, I think that as long as your returned value doesn't violate your data validation parameters you should be okay. Haven't tested this just spit balling here.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to make the drop down list by data validation and specify the list including True and False.

Then you will have following formula to set the data in the drop down cell:

```
=IF(A1=0, True, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but I have an idea.

In case you want the list value to always be False when the cell value =0, you can make the data validation list **True** value as formula instead of the actual `True` value.

1. Create a named formula (Ctrl+F3), name it **True**, and put in the formula  `=IF(A1=0,FALSE,TRUE)` (assuming the cell to check is A1).
2. Now in the data validation list add an item `+True` instead of the True value. The **+ sign** makes the value work as a formula. When one selects +True the value will be TRUE if A1<>0, and FALSE if A1=0.
3. The `False` value can remain as is. So your data validation list will look like this `+True,False`.

If you want your list options to stay as is, and change the values to False according to the specific cell value, you'll have to use a VBA macro.